# UITextView BackGround image iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, textview, background-image

I m working on note app. In which i m creating view like iPhone notes. 
First i took a scroll view and then one image view. After that I m creating a `UITextView` dynamically...  I set the background image of `UITextView`.. 
using this code

```
textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,30,320,400)];
 textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"lines.png"]];
```

Its working perfect in simulator. but when i run my app on device then `UITextView`'s background doesn't display... means it doesn't display lines...
My image size is 365x45...
Can anybody help me why this happen???? Where is the problem???
thanks!!

Comment: What is the name of the image on file system?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once and got grey hair over it. :)

Double check whether your background image file (the .png or whatever) is still boundled with your app. Check this with the project or tartet settings when you have multiple targets.

In my case the file was included in the project but not in the boundle. For reasons that I never understood it was part of the bounle installed on the simulator. It was even there when I deleted the app manually from the simulator's file system. Re-launched the app in the simulator and it was there again.

But when I checked the content of the boundles that where sent to debug devices or the store, the image file was missing.

The same problem may occour to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not currently in front of a Mac. Therefore I quote this out of the top of my head. Basically an .ipa or .app boundle is a zip file. You right-click on that boundle and see, what the context menu offers. It should offer some point similar to "inspect content" or so. Just follow that and do from there. If no such function is offered then rename the file to *.zip. You will get a warning but rename it anyway. After that you can explore it or extract it as any other zip file. At some point in the file system you will find all your resources.

Answer (score 0):

I never used that method. What I do is I put an invisible UITextView over the UIImageView

Comment: but with this way, if i want to scroll the textview then only text moves but background images doesn't move... like only text is moving but lines are still there.....